# advice on displaying graphs and charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Seeking some advice:

I am in Visual Studio 2008 Asp C# environment and like to present charts/graphs to users. Looking for a free solution for displying charts/graphs based on data from MS database.

Some of the products I thought of are : Cacti,Ganglia,Fusion(not free)

If possible please note advantage/disadvantage of the recommended way to go.

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying multiple solutions (Fusion, Microsoft chart control, etc) I decided to go with Google Charts. Since I don't complex requirements, Google Charts will work for me!

The main reason I decide to go with this is that it is extremely easy to do. With one line of code, the chart is done!

I highly recommend Google Charts.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Microsoft's [free chart controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)?

It's built in to Framework 4.0 and available [as a separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en) for Framework 3.5.

Comment: I just checked out the Microsoft chart, for 3.5, it is a very simple chart, you can't even do a pie chart, any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure? The following article shows how you can use the 3.5 charting control to do pie graphs: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/11/25/getting-started-with-the-asp-net-3-5-chart-control.aspx